# About installation issue of postgreSql

Tags: django, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.4, django-postgresql

When I tried to install Postgre SQL in my windows 8.1 when it almost comes near to complete installation showing this error:

Problem Running Post-Install Step. Installation May Not Complete Correctly failed to start the database server.

Please, someone, help me in this case ????

error:

Problem Running Post-Install Step. Installation May Not Complete Correctly failed to start the database server.

Comment: Are you installing 9.4, 9.6? why you don't install postgresql 11?

Comment: i installed postgre 11... but sam eproblem

Comment: Is there more to the error message than that?  Any indication about what the problem actually was?